# Passing a value from JQuery .post to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I just started picking up JQuery today, and for some reason I can't get this simple $.post to work when a form is submitted.

I want to pass the value of 2 as star to my PHP page "update_item.php".

I added an alert and saw that when I clicked submit it would give me the alert, but for some reason the value of 2 just doesn't pass to the php page.

Here's what I have with JQuery:

```
$('#form_edit_item').submit(

    function(){     
        alert("submitting");     
        $.post(
        "edititem.php",
            {star: "2"}, 
        );
    });
```

Here's what I have in update_item.php:

```
$star = $_POST['star'];
echo "Star value: " .$star. "";
```

What am I doing wrong?
Your help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to pass to `update_item.php` why have you passed `"edititem.php"` as the first argument of `$.post()`? There are a few other issues. The trailing comma after `{star: "2"}` may cause issues, and you're not doing anything with the server response.

Comment: You are not doing anything with your ajax response,How did you find it is not working?

Comment: Sorry it was late, so I had the wrong code copied, this is what I wanted to post:     $('#form_edit_item').submit(
        
        function(){     
         alert("submitting");     
            $.post(
       "update_item.php",
                {star: "2"} 
            );
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(url, data, callback, "json");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form_edit_item').submit(

function() {
    alert("submitting");
    $.post("update_item.php", {
        star : "2"
    });
});
```

Remove the trailing comma after `{star : "2"}`. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_item.php",
            data: {
                star: "2" // or 'star: $('#id').val()', or any other value
            }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            // do it when its done or do nothing
        });
```

and in `update_item.php` you should use somthing like that

```
<?php $star=(isset($_POST['star']) ? $_POST['star'] : '');
echo $star; ?>
```

If this won't work, try change `POST` to `GET` so you can check passing value by url (domain.com/update_item.php?star=2)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this code,

```
  <form action="../handler/AjaxHelper.php" method="POST">

  </form>

 $(document).ready(function() {

            $('form').submit(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: this.method,
                    url: this.action,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (result["messageCode"] == 'success')
                        {
                            alert(result["message"]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert(result["message"])
                        }
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                        alert("Please Try Again");
                    }                        
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

In ***AjaxHelper.php***

```
$objLoginHelper = new LoginHelper();
$objLoginHelper = unserialize($_SESSION["LoginInformation"]);
$postDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['txtTopicDate']));
$dataTopics = array($_POST['txtTopicSubject'], $postDate, $_POST['ddlCategories'], $objLoginHelper->getUserLoginId());

$result = array();

try {
    $rp = new Repository();
    $rp->SaveForumTopics($dataTopics);
    $result["messageCode"] = "success";
    $result["message"] = "Category Save Successfully";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $result["messageCode"] = "error";
    $result["message"] = $ex->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($result);
```